# How to use Provider to inject a mock into a Flutter test

Tags: flutter

I want to use Provider to inject dependencies into my Flutter app.

I inject a 'repository' class which calls asynchronous native methods.

For testing purposes I want to inject a mock version of the repository.

How does one do this?

In the application code:

```
void main() {
  runApp(
    MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => Repository()),
      ],
      child: MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}
```

In the test:

```
await tester.pumpWidget(
    MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => Repository()),
      ],
      child: MyApp(),
    ));
```

Whilst the app runs fine, the test fails with the same message as when I omit the provider and just call

`tester.pumpWidget(MyApp());`

The Exception is:

> The following ProviderNotFoundException was thrown building MyHomePage(dirty, state:
> _MyHomePageState#9407e):
> Error: Could not find the correct Provider above this MyHomePage Widget
> ...

main.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'repository.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';


void main() {
  runApp(
    MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => Repository()),
      ],
      child: MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Demo'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  String _days = "0";

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext buildContext) {
  
    final _daysFuture = context.watch<Repository>().daysInSummer();
    return Material(
        child: FutureBuilder(
            future: _daysFuture,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                _days = snapshot.data;
                return Scaffold(
                  appBar: AppBar(
                    title: Text(widget.title),
                  ),
                  body: Center(
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text(
                          'demo text',
                        ),
                        Text(
                          "$_days",
                          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline2,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      context.read<Repository>().addDayInSummer();
                    },
                    tooltip: 'Increment',
                    child: Icon(Icons.add),
                  ), 
                );
              } else {
                return Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  children: [
                    Text('Waiting for initialisation'),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 16,
                    ),
                    CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  ],
                );
              }
            }));
  }
}
```

widget_test.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:summer/main.dart';

class Repository with ChangeNotifier {
  int days = 0;

  @override
  Future<String> addDayInSummer() {
    days++;
    notifyListeners();
    return daysInSummer();
  }

  @override
  Future<String> daysInSummer() {
    Future<String> s = Future.delayed(
      Duration(milliseconds: 2),
      () => days.toString(),
    );
    notifyListeners();
    return s;
  }
}

void main() {
  testWidgets('Counter increments smoke test', (WidgetTester tester) async {
    
    await tester.pumpWidget(MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => Repository()),
      ],
      child: MyApp(),
    ));

    // Verify that our counter starts at 0.
    expect(find.text('0/90'), findsOneWidget);
    expect(find.text('1/90'), findsNothing);

    //Tap the '+' icon and trigger a frame.
    await tester.tap(find.byIcon(Icons.add));
    await tester.pump();

    // Verify that our counter has incremented.
    expect(find.text('0/90'), findsNothing);
    expect(find.text('1/90'), findsOneWidget);
  });
}
```

Comment: This answer might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63595169/96944

Answer (score 0):

You can force it to be interpreted as a `Repository` either by storing it as a local variable or cast it with `MockRepository as Repository`.

Below is a test which runs green on the app example you have provided:

```
class MockRepo extends Repository {
  int days = 0;

  @override
  Future<String> addDayInSummer() {
    days++;
    notifyListeners();
    return daysInSummer();
  }

  @override
  Future<String> daysInSummer() {
    Future<String> s = Future.delayed(
      Duration(milliseconds: 2),
      () => days.toString(),
    );
    return s;
  }
}

void main() {
  testWidgets('Counter increments smoke test', (WidgetTester tester) async {
    final Repository repo = MockRepo();
    await tester.pumpWidget(MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => repo),
      ],
      child: MyApp(),
    ));
    await tester.pumpAndSettle();

    // Verify that our counter starts at 0.
    expect(find.text('0'), findsOneWidget);
    expect(find.text('1'), findsNothing);

    //Tap the '+' icon and trigger a frame.
    await tester.tap(find.byIcon(Icons.add));
    await tester.pumpAndSettle();

    // Verify that our counter has incremented.
    expect(find.text('0'), findsNothing);
    expect(find.text('1'), findsOneWidget);
  });
}
```