# How to unit test a class that is created by provider?

Tags: flutter, flutter-test, flutter-provider

So let's say I have a Counter class like this

```
class Counter extends ChangeNotifier {
  int _i = 0;

  int get myCounter => _i;
  
  void increment() {
    _i++;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void decrement() {
    _i--;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

I want to write a test file for it, so I expose its instance like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59735366/13192893). The problem is, after I expose it, how do I access the instance of the class I just created? Like say, I increased `_i` value through a button, how will I access the instance that is created by `Provider` in order to test it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was looking to do the same but then I found this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/67704136/8111212

Basically, you can get the context from a widget, then you can use the context to get the provider state

Btw, you should test a public variable like `i` instead of `_i`

Code sample:

```
testWidgets('showDialog', (WidgetTester tester) async {
  await tester.pumpWidget(MaterialApp(home: Material(child: Container())));
  final BuildContext context = tester.element(find.byType(Scaffold)); // It could  be  final BuildContext context = tester.element(find.byType(Container)) depending on your app

  final Counter provider = Provider.of<Counter>(context, listen: false);
  expect(provider.i, equals(3));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You first initialize the Provider in your main.dart file using

```
ChangeNotifierProvider
```

after that you can use the class anywhere in your code by either using the Consumer widget or by using:

```
final counter = Provider.of<Counter>(context)
```

[Here](https://medium.com/theotherdev-s/starting-with-flutter-a-simple-guide-for-provider-401b25957989) is a good post/tutorial about how to use Provider

Comment: Yes, thank you. But this is in Flutter test, There's no way to use context to access it. Says, I increase the `_i` value, there's no way for me to verify whether It will increase or not because I can't access the instance that is created by `Provider/ChangeNotifierProvider`.